# I just setup python django and Im unable to import

Tags: django, python-3.x, web

I just finished installing Python and Django. I followed everything in a tutorial video and I wrote the most simple code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
   return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello world!</h1>")
```

I imported it to the URL and it works as expected but the problem is I get this error:[Unable to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWGbZ.png) I don't know why it is saying this because it works well. what is wrong with the program? 
And I have the same import problem on other files too.

Comment: You definitely need to indent the return statement. Is that accurate above? Or just a formatting issue?

Comment: I don't like to nitpick, but I see it a lot so I feel like I need to say it. Taking a screenshot of a red wavy line does nothing to help us solve your problem. If you want to include something helpful, include the stack trace as text.

Comment: Its just VS code extension warning. Dont worry about that extension. There is no issue with your code :)